# How to invoke IntelliJ rename refactor from custom ToolWindow?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I'm developing an IntelliJ plugin that has its own tool window. The plugin should invoke IntelliJ's built-in rename refactor function to rename a variable when the user presses a key. When I run my example the following exception is thrown when I press a key to invoke the rename refactor function:

```
2020-05-16 23:03:17,741 [  41062]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - EventQueue.isDispatchThread()=false Toolkit.getEventQueue()=com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue@574ed46a
Current thread: Thread[JavaFX Application Thread,6,Idea Thread Group] 648578026
Write thread (volatile): Thread[AWT-EventQueue-0,6,Idea Thread Group] 807407917com.intellij.openapi.diagnostic.Attachment@339b1167 
com.intellij.openapi.diagnostic.RuntimeExceptionWithAttachments: EventQueue.isDispatchThread()=false Toolkit.getEventQueue()=com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue@574ed46a
Current thread: Thread[JavaFX Application Thread,6,Idea Thread Group] 648578026
Write thread (volatile): Thread[AWT-EventQueue-0,6,Idea Thread Group] 807407917com.intellij.openapi.diagnostic.Attachment@339b1167
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.assertIsWriteThread(ApplicationImpl.java:1068)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.startWrite(ApplicationImpl.java:1154)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runWriteAction(ApplicationImpl.java:974)
    at MyToolWindowFactory.handle(MyToolWindowFactory.java:55)
    at MyToolWindowFactory.handle(MyToolWindowFactory.java:17)
```

I thought that calling the `setName` function as a lambda inside `ApplicationManager.getApplication().runWriteAction` would work, but apparently not. How can I get it to work?

Here is the complete code I used.

```
import com.intellij.openapi.application.ApplicationManager;
import com.intellij.openapi.fileEditor.FileEditorManager;
import com.intellij.openapi.project.Project;
import com.intellij.openapi.vfs.VirtualFile;
import com.intellij.openapi.wm.ToolWindow;
import com.intellij.openapi.wm.ToolWindowFactory;
import com.intellij.psi.*;
import javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;

import javax.swing.*;

public class MyToolWindowFactory implements ToolWindowFactory, EventHandler<KeyEvent> {

    PsiField[] variables;

    @Override
    public void createToolWindowContent(@NotNull Project project, @NotNull ToolWindow toolWindow) {
        final JFXPanel fxPanel = new JFXPanel();
        JComponent component = toolWindow.getComponent();

        ApplicationManager.getApplication().invokeLater(() -> {
            PsiClass currentClass = getCurrentClass(project);
            variables = currentClass.getFields();

            Scene scene = new Scene(new VBox(), 400, 250);
            scene.setOnKeyPressed(this);
            fxPanel.setScene(scene);
            fxPanel.requestFocus();
        });

        component.getParent().add(fxPanel);
    }

    private PsiClass getCurrentClass(Project project) {
        // Get the currently selected file.
        FileEditorManager manager = FileEditorManager.getInstance(project);
        VirtualFile[] files = manager.getSelectedFiles();
        VirtualFile currentFile = files[0];

        // Get the PsiClass for the currently selected file.
        PsiFile psiFile = PsiManager.getInstance(project).findFile(currentFile);
        PsiJavaFile psiJavaFile = (PsiJavaFile)psiFile;
        final PsiClass[] classes = psiJavaFile.getClasses();

        return classes[0];
    }

    @Override
    public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
        ApplicationManager.getApplication().runWriteAction(() -> {
            variables[0].setName("newVariableName");
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to get it to work is to call the rename function from the `WriteCommandAction.runWriteCommandAction` method. In addition calling just `setName` only renames the variable declaration. To rename all references to the variable I first searched for all the variable's references with the `ReferencesSearch.search` method, and then called `handleElementRename` on each reference.

```
public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
    Runnable r = ()->
    {
        for (PsiReference reference : ReferencesSearch.search(variables[0])) {
            reference.handleElementRename(variableName);
        }
        variables[0].setName(variableName);
    }
    WriteCommandAction.runWriteCommandAction(project, r);
}
```

Got the hint to use `WriteCommandAction` from here:
https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206754235